# How to write a viewPager inside a recyclerView full height

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a RecyclerView with a ViewPager inside it, which in turn have another recyclerView. The recyclerView inside a ViewPager don't load whole items, but only one, and don't scroll to show the rest of the items

I have tried to set the layout_height of the two recycler view with wrap_content, and also nested it inside a nestedSCrollView, without success.

```
// First outside recyclerview
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView        
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

// cell item with viewPager
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

// recyclerView inside viewPager
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView         
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I expect that the outside recyclerView fill the whole height of the items, instead the recycler view inside seams that don't load the whole items but the only one that is visible in the screen, without scroll.

**EDIT**

fragment__events_detail (layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/toolbar__height"
    tools:layout_marginTop="@dimen/actionbar__height">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The first cell of the recycler view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- img video club -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgVideoClub"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[12]" />

    <!-- play icon -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/playIcon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/play_icon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_orange_outline_red_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/prohibition_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Segnala abuso"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The second cell with a tablayout and a viewpager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment inside first tab of the viewPager with a recyclerView inside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/toolbar__height"
    tools:layout_marginTop="@dimen/actionbar__height">

    <!-- header -->
    <TextView
        android:text="Eventi"
        style="@style/header_txtStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!-- separator -->
    <View
        android:background="@color/separator_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

    <!-- container events search -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/main__horizzontalPadding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/main__horizzontalPadding"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- search icon -->
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/search_icon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/events__home_eventsSearchEditTxt"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:hint="Cerca eventi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- separator -->
    <View
        android:background="@color/separator_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="3dp"/>


    <!-- range time events -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/main__horizzontalPadding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/main__horizzontalPadding"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/events__home_thisWeekTimeTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Questa settimana"
            android:textColor="@color/events__home_itemNotSelected"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/events__home_rangeTimeTxtSize"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/events__home_nextWeekTimeTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Prossima settimana"
            android:textColor="@color/events__home_itemNotSelected"
            android:textSize="@dimen/events__home_rangeTimeTxtSize"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/events__home_calendarRangeTimeContainer"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/events__home_thisWeekTimeTxt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/events__home_calendarRangeTimeContainer"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/events__home_calendarRangeTimeTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/events__home_rangeTimeTxtSize"
                android:textColor="@color/events__home_itemNotSelected"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar__icon" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The items of the second recyclerView

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/row__events_home_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/event__background_rounded"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/calendarIcon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/clockIcon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/clockIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/clockIcon"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/calendar__icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row__events_home_dateEvent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/events__home_secondaryTextColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/calendarIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/calendarIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/calendarIcon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row__events_home_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row__events_home_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/row__events_home_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/row__events_home_title" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/locationIcon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/location__icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row__events_home_locationEventName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/events__home_secondaryTextColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/locationIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/locationIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/locationIcon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clockIcon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/locationIcon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/locationIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/locationIcon"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock__icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row__events_home_timeEvent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/events__home_secondaryTextColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/clockIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/clockIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/clockIcon" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/row__events_home_interestBtn"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_orange_outline"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/clockIcon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/clockIcon">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/interest__events_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Mi interessa"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/row__events_home_buyBtn"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_orange_outline"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/locationIcon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/locationIcon">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Prenota"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView11"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Prenota" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ticket__events_buy" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: in this code all the views are separate and the viewPager is outside the recyclerview. but why you want to use viewpager inside recyclerview? you should have a list item and inflate that as a recyclerview item

Comment: Hi @H.sanati, thank you for reply. For reasons of space I insert all the views in one part, but in my code the viewpager is inside an outside recycler view as a view item. I needed a think like this https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7895040/25775336/82bdfe58-32c0-11e7-943e-c7c1e3107b67.png

Comment: please edit your post and put all the codes that relates to your problem so the problem would be  clear and the answer would be the thing that you want exactly. I should see the code to suggest you a solution.

Comment: @H.sanati i have edited my post. Thanks